# When I click on the hyperlink with the pointer, it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Help me figure out why "HOME" hyperlink doesn't work please. When I go on the hyperlink it is impossible to click on it with the pointer. I tried everything. I'm a rookie, please help.

```css
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10%;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: black;
}

.video {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.responsive-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <figure>
    <a href="index.html">
      <figcaption>HOME</figcaption>
    </a>
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/..." width="1080" height="459" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Happy to present you the final answer. IT WORKS :). I test and localize knew where you got it wrong, you messed up the code in  tag. Use my code below which works well for reference.

All you need to do is go to vimeo and copy the embedded link again. You somehow corrupted vimeo link code before. Now you can green tick this answer we got it done this time :).

```
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/259411563">A Love Letter to Winter</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/thenorthface">The North Face</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
  
  <div class="video">
    <figure>
      <a href="index.html">
        <figcaption>HOME</figcaption>
      </a>
      <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/259411563" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

its not working because you added css for figcaption as pointer-events:none.
delete that line the it may work.

Comment: Use Ctrl + F5 To re Cache stylesheet.

Comment: I did, still not working, I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is fully redundant. You delete it and the hyperlink will work perfectly

```
cursor: pointer;
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: I did, still not working. Could it be iFrame fault? Maybe it covers the link preventing to click on it?

Comment: I just code testing on my computer. You have to remove both class="video" and the whole tag iframe to let the hyperlink shown and after it shown then the link on it will work well

Comment: Thanks man for your help. Unfortunately I can't remove iFrame tag. The page consists on an embed video with only an hyperlink under it that send to website homepage.

Comment: I just be careful and check it one more time. Yes, that's all we need to fix. We fully solved it. Please green tick my answer to make it final answer to let people know that we got it done already :).